# Possibility of getting a UK tourist visa if I am 23 years old and unemployed, supported by father who will be travelling with me

Tags: visas, uk

We are family of 4 members.We want to go to the UK for 2 days and hence apply for a tourist visa. My father is going to sponsor the entire trip to the UK. Mother is housewife, brother is 26 years old doing his MA and I completed my B.tech this year but I am preparing for a competitive exam therefore I'm not currently employed. What status should I write:

- Employed full time
- Employed part time
- Student (working)
- Student (non working)
- Supported by spouse/partner/other
- Unemployed

Can I be considered as dependent child?

Should I write unemployed or supported by Father in this option?

Is there is possibility of denial of visa as I am unemployed right now but sponsored by my father?

If yes what other options are there so that it gets accepted?

Please help as we have booked the tour with a travel company and need to apply as soon as possible.

Comment: I hope that tour is refundable. Visas are never guaranteed, and it's not a good plan to spend money you won't get back if you aren't issued a visa.

Comment: We can't say anything about the possibility about you getting a visa. It simply depends on too many things. But being young and unemployed is often not a combination in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

The only of the options you list that would not be a blatant lie are "supported by family" and "unemployed". Lying can emphatically *not* be recommended -- that will make it somewhere between very hard and impossible to qualify for a visa *ever*.

It may sound like you can squeeze in under "supported by spouse/partner/**other**", but that would not really be an advantage for you. They're going to look closely at your *particular* circumstances no matter which box you check, so what your goal needs to be is not to micro-optimize which box you think gives a slightly higher chance, but to avoid them thinking you're trying to hide something. They hate *dishonesty* much more than just about any truth you could possibly tell.

Yes, as a young person with a fresh education and no job, there's a definite risk that the ECO will think it could be attractive for you to stay in the UK illegally to seek work. You can't escape that suspicion by tactical answers to the application questions. What you need to do is convince them that it is *more advantageous* for you to return home than to abscond and stay illegally. How to do that depends entirely on what *makes* that advantageous to you -- if your family is well off and your education is one that gives you a good shoot at a nice *legal* job in your home country, things will go much smoother than if you're dirt poor with no prospects locally.

If you can't lift that documentary burden, you probably won't be going. Wait until you're more settled in your life instead.

---

Note that it probably *will* raise eyebrows that you're apparently proposing a family vacation in the UK lasting only 2 days. You don't write where you're from, but since the UK's nearest neighbors are all EU members whose citizens don't need visa, I suppose you're so far away that the hassle and cost of traveling to the UK would hardly be worth it for only a couple of days.

A suspicious ECO (and they're paid to be suspicious) might get the idea that the entire family is only proposing the vacation as a pretext for getting the son/daughter into the UK to get a chance at a better life, and that 2 days were all they could convincingly budget for.

Comment: Thank you Henning Makholm, can I be considered dependent if I am 23 years old? can I fill in both options 'Unemployed' and 'Supported by family' ?

Comment: @vivek: As I explained, essentially nothing depends on which of those two boxes you squeeze yourself into. The condition you must satisfy **is the same no matter which** in both cases, namely convince the ECO that you have a good verifiable reason to leave the UK at the end of the trip. Nothing else matters. The only difference is that if you tie yourself into a knot to present yourself as "supporeted by spouse/partner" there is a risk that the ECO will think you're hiding something, and that this risk disappears if you instead **tell the truth** that you're unemployed!